# Bringing up spring application with OAuth2Client when AuthServer is not reachable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have configured an Oauth2 client using spring-boot, spring-security using oauth2client. This will be a fat client residing on client's machine.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly when I am connected to internet and when AuthServer can be reached. However if for some reason, AuthServer can't be reached; be it proxy or lack of internet my application won't even start giving exception as follows

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of ....`

Is there any way in spring-boot/spring-security can be configured to keep on trying in background and letting the application to be up?  Something like a placeholder/offline bean which gets populated once connection is established?